# Подключить карусель не получается

Tags: javascript, css3, html5, вёрстка

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".carousel").owlCarousel({
  responsive : {
   0 : {
    items : 1,
    nav : true
   }
  }
  navText : ""
 })
})
```

```html
<section class="rewview" data-stellar-background-ratio="0.5">
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-12">
    <h2 class="s_dark">Отзывы наших учеников</h2>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="carousel">
     <div class="rewview__item">
      123
     </div>
     <div class="rewview__item">
      321
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Поключаем `jquery`
2. Подключаем [слайдер](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/basic.html)

   - локально, предварительно скачав с сайта
     или
   - https://cdnjs.com/libraries/OwlCarousel2

описание по установке слайдера - [OwlCarousel2/docs/started-installation](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/docs/started-installation.html)

Пример

```js
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
  loop: true,
  margin: 10,
  nav: true,
  responsiveClass: true,
  responsive: {
    0: {
      items: 1
    },
    600: {
      items: 3
    },
    1000: {
      items: 5
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
  <div class="item"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x200"></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x200/ff0000/ffffff"></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x200/0000ff/ffffff"></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x200/000000/ffffff"></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x200"></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x200/ff0000/ffffff"></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x200/0000ff/ffffff"></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x200/000000/ffffff"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: я это все знаю, и если в этом была проблема, я сюда не написал бы

Comment: Извиняюсь бомбануло все работает спасибо